# Any idea why FFT of rectangular pulse behaves like this?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

If I do the FFT of the "usual" rectangular pulse function I get this "weird" result:
[image: FFT of rectangular function]

However, If I roll the same signal by half (`f = np.roll(f, f.size//2)`)  and calculate the FFT, I get what I was expecting if I had used the non-rolled signal, i.e., get the *sinc* function as result:
[image: FFT of rolled rectangular function]

By the way, if I do what most people do, i.e., if I plot the magnitude of the spectrum (instead of just the real part) of either signal (usual or rolled) I'll get exactly the same result (that resembles closer to the *sinc*).

[image]
[image]

I was expecting to get the *sinc* function from the real part of the FFT of the "usual" rectangular function.

Does anybody know why do I need to roll the rectangular function in order to produce the *sinc* function?

I'm using scipy's fft.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming.

Comment: The origin for the FFT is in the leftmost sample. Your `t` axis in the plots is ignored by the FFT, it assumes `t=0:N-1`. If your pulse is centered around 0, you get your expected result, a purely real, symmetric frequency domain plot. If it is shifted (as in the first case), then the phase component of the result of the FFT is not 0, thus you get a non-zero imaginary component. You plot only the real part, which will bounce up and down a lot. The magnitude is the same, shifting in the time domain only changes the phase in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the shift property of the FFT (and IFFT).  If you circularly shift the data in one domain, it's the same as multiplying by a complex sinusoid in the other domain, with the frequency of that modulation proportional to the amount of the shift.

Works the same way for shifts in either the time domain or frequency domain, causing modulation in the other domain.

For "unshifted" results, the 0 point (or circular symmetry center for strictly real FFT results) usually needs to be at the first element of the FFT or IFFT input vector, not the middle.

See: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/Shift_Theorem.html